# Is it possible to disable source/destination check on lightsail instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Just like with ec2?

I have some instances in lightsail and I was planning to make one of them a VPN server.
But for to get to the other instances in lightsail VPC, I would have to disable this feature.

I've been looking at the CLI documentation and found nothing about

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lightsail/index.html